# How can you access the properties of a json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new to nodejs and I have a service which I cannot modify which returns a json with the following form,

I can't access the properties of the json, can someone help me?

`{ '{"DATA":"aa"}': '' }`

Comment: so, the JSON is the KEY of an object? never seen that before

Answer (score 0):

This function will work:

```
Object.keys({ '{"DATA":"aa"}': '' })[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access a property value whose name has special characters:

```js
var x = { '{"DATA":"aa"}': 'foo' }
console.log( x['{"DATA":"aa"}'] );
```

You can also use the [`for...in` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to access every enumerable property's name/value pair:

```js
var x = { '{"DATA":"aa"}': 'foo', 'abc': 123 }
for (const prop in x) {
  console.log( `${prop}: ${x[prop]}` );
}
```